# Packaging a multiplayer game in unreal

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-4

I have created a new project using the third person template. I set the number of players to two in the play settings as well as using a dedicated server.

How do I package the project so that I can run the server and connect to it with clients? So far when I package it all I get is an exe that starts the game like a normal single-player game.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the Engine from Source in order to get the DevelopmentSever config as its not available on the LauncherVersion of the Engine. Pull the source from the github, run a few .bat files and you have the source. Compile it. Go to the game project directory on your drive and switch engine version for the project while opening .uproject. It will process this and generate the requisite files. 
Open solution file for the game and select DevelopmentSever config and build. You will get the DedicatedServer executable file in the binaries.
Open the project and package file. 
You have the game executable and server executable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two multiplayer hosting modes with Unreal: Client-Server and Peer-To-Peer. The second is easy to set up and is why you get a single executable file when packaging (any client can start a non-dedicated server). If you want a proper dedicated Server, you will need to write one yourself.